Google Test in Qt Creator GUI do not run when successful
I am using Google Test in Qt Creator to test some library code. The below test checks if variables are initialized correctly, both in SetUp() and in the test itself:
#include <gmock/gmock-matchers.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>

#include "test_vectors.h"
#include "../some-library/library_files.h" // containing frame and payload classes

using namespace testing;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

namespace somelib {

    class TestSomeLibrary : public ::testing::Test
    {
    public:
        TestSomeLibrary()
        {

        }

        void SetUp()
        {
            cout << "Opening up serial... ";
            serialPort = new QSerialPort();
            serialPort->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

            cout << "Setting up serial... ";
            serialPort->setPortName("COM4");
            serialPort->setBaudRate(3625000);
            serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
            serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
            serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);

            cout << "Serial set up and open!" << endl;

        }

        void TearDown()
        {
            cout << "Tearing down!" << endl;
            delete testBytes;
            cout << "Test Bytes Deleted" << endl;
            delete testF;
            cout << "TestF Deleted" << endl;
            delete testP;
            cout << "TestP Deleted" << endl;

            cout << "Closing port...";
            serialPort->close();
            cout << " Port Closed" << endl;
            delete serialPort;
            cout << "Serial port deleted";
        }

        ~TestSomeLibrary ()
        {

        }

        frame* testF;
        payload* testP;

        QByteArray* testBytes;
        QSerialPort* serialPort;

    };

    TEST_F(TestSomeLibrary , test_create)
    {
        testP = new payload(5, test_vector);
        testF = new frame(*testP);
        testBytes = new QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(testF->getVectorised().data()), testF->getVectorised().size());

        EXPECT_TRUE(testP != NULL);
        EXPECT_TRUE(testF != NULL);
        EXPECT_TRUE(testBytes != NULL);
        EXPECT_TRUE(serialPort != NULL);
    }

}


When I run the tests, I only get the following:
"Test summary: 0 passes, 0 fails". When I try to debug the test, nothing happens no matter how many breakpoints I put.
The tests seem to pass because when I change any of the EXPECT_TRUE tests to check if the variables ARE null, they fail.
I'm building using Qt5.15.13 MSVC2019 64-bit, CMake version 3.27.7, and MSVC runtime version /MTd (MultiThreadedDebug).

Does this answer your question? Google Test not finding any tests
